# How to upload asset element on its own, not into an asset field (frontend form)

Tags: assets, frontend-form

I have read [this resource](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/assets-fields.html#creating-new-assets) about uploading a file to an asset field on an entry, but I believe I need to create the asset on its own because the asset has 2 custom fields associated with it that I want to define upon its creation. Is there not something like an 'assets/save-asset' action I can use to save an asset element without having to attach it to an entry?

Update: With Marion's help I'm a little closer. Side note: apparently 'assets/save-asset' is now depreciated in favor of 'assets/upload' so I'm using that. Here is my form:

```
              <form method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                {{ csrfInput() }}
                {{ actionInput('assets/upload') }}
                {{ hiddenInput('folderId', 7) }}
                {{ hiddenInput('title', 'cool image')}}
                <input name='file' type='file'>
                <input type='submit' value='submit'>
              </form>
```

But I am now getting a 400 Bad Request error with the message `No file was uploaded`. What am I doing wrong to not have my file attach correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I figured out that I had to name the asset field as "assets-upload" in order for it to work. I found this out by inspecting the asset upload button in the CP. Here is my working form code:

```
          <form method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            {{ csrfInput() }}
            {{ actionInput('assets/upload') }}
            {{ hiddenInput('folderId', 7) }}
            {{ hiddenInput('title', 'cool image')}}
            <input name="assets-upload" type='file'>
            <input type='submit' value='submit'>
          </form>
```

And remember, you can get your intended folderId also by inspecting the volume folders in the CP to see what the ID is.

Comment: I'm also trying to use a frontend form to set a custom field on an asset upload. Where you able to get that part to work? My asset is uploading fine, using this approach. But I can't get it to save a value to the asset's custom field.

Comment: @MichaelTodd were you using 'fields[yourFieldName]' (or 'fields[yourFieldName][]' if it's a relational field) as the field name?

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed an `assets/save-asset` controller. You will find it in `vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/AssetsController.php`, the `actionSaveAsset()` function.

Comment: Ok great. For some reason I have a hard time reading the controller docs compared to other class docs. What is the `name` that I would need to use on my file upload field to place the file into the created asset element? If the answer is `file` then I suppose I should have tried to guess my way through this one lol.

Comment: I edited my question to show where I'm at now. I was able to find the folderId by inspecting the folder in the CP.